# Mysql Myisam re-using auto-incremented ids that are deleted

Tags: mysql, primary-key, auto-increment, myisam

I have a table: test

id int(10) auto-increment
name char(36)

Now let us say my WHOLE table it filled from ID 1000 => max unique id number.
Id 1 - 1000 = deleted previously.

Question 1; WILL mysql re-use these deleted id's?
Question 2; If not, how to I go about having auto-increment or whatever to re-use unique identifier that does not exist in table?

The reason I am asking, is that my table will consist of alot of entries, and that alot of entries will be deleted all the time. What happens when I "run-out-of-id" when using auto-increment?

Thanks for any enlightment on this :)

-Tom

Answer (score 3):

1. > WILL mysql re-use these deleted id's?

   When `mysqld` starts, it determines the next value for every `AUTO_INCREMENT` column by finding the maximum of the incumbent records (and adding 1).  Therefore, if you delete the record with the highest value and restart the server, the deleted id will indeed be reused.

   Otherwise, values will only be reused if you manually alter the next `AUTO_INCREMENT` value (this is *not* recommended as it is not concurrency-safe):

   ```
   ALTER TABLE foo AUTO_INCREMENT = 12345;
   ```
2. > If not, how to I go about having auto-increment or whatever to re-use unique identifier that does not exist in table?

   Generally speaking, you don't: consider redesigning your data structure so that inserts/deletes do not happen in this fashion, or else use a larger integer type (`BIGINT UNSIGNED` is 8 bytes, so can go up to 2^64 or ~10^19).
3. > What happens when I "run-out-of-id" when using auto-increment?

   As stated in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-auto-increment.html):

   > Use the smallest integer data type for the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column that is large enough to hold the maximum sequence value you will need. When the column reaches the upper limit of the data type, the next attempt to generate a sequence number fails.

Answer (score 0):

you need to reset the autoincrement, Autoincrement just keep incrementing and won't go back at least if you don't set it.

```
alter table tablename auto_increment=value
```

like this

```
mysql> alter table t1 auto_increment=200;
Query OK, 202 rows affected (0.04 sec)
Records: 202  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

EDIT:
if you delete some records, the auto_increment will be "last value+1", it doesn't matter what you do, only if you delete the full table you'll be able to 'start over'.

The best would be with a trigger, but triggers can't alter tables (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)

So your last option is a store procedure take a look here: [Is it possible to alter a table in mySql via stored procedures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547804/is-it-possible-to-alter-a-table-in-mysql-via-stored-procedures)

Which is not recommended.

Comment: ok, but any way to set it to do this auto? And will it skip the existing IDs when auto-incrementing after a reset?

Answer (score 0):

1. No, MySQL won't reuse the IDs from deleted records
2. Do you really need to? If the type of your autoincrement column is BIGINT, you've got 18446744073709551615 possible IDs